# WordPress Internal Server Error

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, wordpress, bbpress

Causing full Virtual Memory Usage!! 3,500 / 3500 MB

Error log provided by hosting:

> [Thu Dec 05 16:33:34 2013] [error] [client 123.164.66.67] (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn’t create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/sparkyh1/public_html/androidizer.com/index.php, referer: http://www.androidizer.com/support/forum/android-application-support/
>   
> [Thu Dec 05 16:33:34 2013] [error] [client 123.164.66.67] (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn’t create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/sparkyh1/public_html/androidizer.com/index.php, referer: http://www.androidizer.com/support/forum/android-application-support/
>   
> [Thu Dec 05 16:33:35 2013] [error] [client 116.25.65.8] (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn’t create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/sparkyh1/public_html/androidizer.com/index.php, referer: http://www.androidizer.com/support/forum/android-application-support/
>   
> .....

I'm on WordPress. I think the issue is with bbpress and I disabled all plugins via phpmyadmin. But, still the issue is not going away.

Answer (score 0):

try use default .htaccess file ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```